# C++: What is the difference between an include directive and a header file?

Tags: c++, inheritance, include, header-files

From what I understand an include directive is any `.cpp`-file that is inherited (if thats the right word) and a header file is a file that has a `.h` appended to the filename. In our C++ class it was very ambiguous (constantly switching (natural) languages) but from what I've understood headers are only the declarations of functions and the other include directives then define those functions, is that right?
Any help appreciated :)

Comment: ***From what I understand an include directive is any .cpp-file that is inherited (if thats the right word)*** no this is not the right word. Also you normally do not include .cpp files at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#include` is a pre processor directive. Pre processor directives *direct* the behaviour of the pre processor. The pre processor *processes* i.e. modifies the source code prior to compilation.

The pre processor replaces `#include` directives with the content of the file that is the argument of the directive. The files that are included in this way are called header files because they are typically placed at the beginning (head) of the file. So, `#include <iostream>` will be replaced by the content of the header file named `iostream` (except, the standard library headers such as `iostream` do not necessarilly exist as files).

Inclusion of header files with the directive allows using the same header in the beginning of multiple source files. However, C++ standard disallows multiple definitions of functions and variables (though there are some exceptions) across multiple source files. This is why header files typically only contain declarations of functions and variables, not definitions. It is the declarations that the compiler must know of the functions and variables in order to understand the program the uses them.

> What is the difference between an include directive and a header file?

As you seem from my description of both include directive, and header file, they are quite different concepts. Your question is analogous to: "What is the difference between a pen, and a short story". You can write a short story with a pen, but they are not very comparable as they are so different concepts. Similarly, you can include a header file with the include directive, but they are hardly comparable.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. My confusion must've come from the fact that the German Wikipedia article "Header-Datei" redirects to "Include directive" in English.

Comment: @Eman I see. That would explain the confusion. As you can see, you cannot really assume what kind of relationship two things have from a Wikipedia redirection :)

Comment: "are called header files" except when they are not.

Answer (score 4):

A "directive" refers to a [preprocessor macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor), so an "include directive" just means

```
#include "foo.h"
```

A header file is just the actual file that you would be pulling in using the [`#include` directive](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include).

Comment: @Eman There is no difference, filenames have no inherent meaning to the `#include` directive.  A directive is an instruction: "include this file"; a header file is a "thing" (file) that gets included.

Comment: @Eman Read the answer again:  An "include directive" is a line of code; a "header file" is a file that is intended to be reference by an include directive.  That's a pretty clear response to your question "what is the difference"

Answer (score 0):

> what the difference is (if there is any) between the files you include
>   that do and don't have a ".h" in them.

Answer - there is no difference to the 'include directive'.  The compiler often does care, but will not complain if you place the include correctly.

---

Perhaps an example might help.  But first a summary:

The include directive

-- is not code

-- marks (in the original code) where the include directive is removed and replaced to create the compilation unit

-- and identifies what file contains the replacement text

The replacement text can be any kind of text, code or not.  All syntax rules still apply, and the compiler never gets to see the 'include directive', just the contents of the include-directive-file.

---

With that in mind, in the following snippet of real functioning code, note that in the middle of a class method attribute, I have an "include directive" which specifies a file :

```
int exec_3of3() // EXPERIMENT 3 of 3
  {
     // copied your data from the SO post to a file named 'dumy447.inc'
     // using my editor (emacs) I lightly modified the file:
     //      1) inserted a quote at the beginning
     //      2) removed the only line feed (after the 2500)
     //      3) appended a quote to the end of the file (after 11161)
     // With these  3 changes, the file can be used directly in the code!

     std::stringstream ssIn (

#include "./dumy447.inc"

     );
     assert(ssIn.good());
     // BAM! - a stream filled with your text data

  ...
```

I think the include directive is clearly visible ... it is the single line in this snippet that has a "#include" at the beginning.

In this example, the file name specified is not executable code at all, and the file extent is unimportant, except that, by convention, it should not be .hh (nor .hpp) nor .cc (nor .cpp).  (These can work too, but might be more confusing to your readers.)

The file is simple text that has one line:

```
" 2500 19325 74348 68955 ...  48428 83799 91649 11161 "

^                                                     ^
starts with double quote     and ends with double quote
```

The triple dots means that I have suppressed a lot of info.  For example, this file contains 1 line of approximately 14757 characters, all digits and spaces.

---

In summary:

The "include directive" has few restrictions of what and where.  Your compiler complains if you do it wrong.

The result of preprocessing the code is called a "compilation unit".

The "compilation unit" has all the code of the original file (which contains the 'include directive') but that no longer contains the 'include directive'.

The 'include directive' has been replaced by the contents of the file, in this case a text file describing some data.

The 'include directive' pays no attention to the file extent, neither '.hh' or '.cc'.  It is used to pre-process the various pieces of file into a "compilation unit", for submittal to the compiler.